# How does one replace MarkupExtension in a Windows Store App?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, markup-extensions

It appears that Microsoft has done away with the MarkupExtension class in Windows Store Apps altogether. This means that there's no x:Static any more (among other things). Is there any replacement for it at all ? If not, why ? What's the new technique for providing static members in XAML (e.g. as ConverterParameters in Bindings) ?